# Is there a concise jQuery selector for a list of specific input types (type='text', etc)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, textinput

Is there a more concise way to do this?

```
// exclude all HTML 4 except text and password, but include HTML 5 except search
var inputSelector = "textarea,input[type='text'],input[type='password'],input[type='color']," +
    "input[type='date'],input[type='datetime'],input[type='datetime-local']," +
    "input[type='email'],input[type='month'],input[type='number'],input[type='range']," +
    "input[type='tel'],input[type='time'],input[type='url'],input[type='week']";
```

**Note:** I cannot use the .Not() function because this selector will be used in the .delegate() function. Also, it would be best if I could make the selector include future input types (HTML 6 >) by default.

**Answer:**

Here is what I have now. Much better than before. If it can be refined more please let me know.

```
// exclude all HTML 4 except text and password, but include HTML 5 except search
var inputSelector = "textarea,input:not([type='checkbox'],[type='radio'],[type='button']," +
    "[type='image'],[type='submit'],[type='reset'],[type='file'],[type='search'])";
```

Note that it also includes input and textarea, which also mean future additions to the HTML spec will be included by default (to those who didn't think this was possible).

Comment: If you need special cases then you have no choice

Comment: Since when does `.delegate()` _not_ support `:not()`?

Comment: Delegate supports not? Can you show an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/FD5nL/

Comment: "Also, it would be best if I could make the selector include future input types (HTML 6 >) by default." How would you realistically expect such a selector to work?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I said it would be best, I didn't say it was a requirement.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL - I'd appreciate if you make your jsfiddle into an answer instead of a question. If that works I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: $("input:not([type='radio'], [type='text'])") .. Since you have very few type of inputs which are NOT included, why not use those ?

Comment: I agree with @xFortyFourx, and his coment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both MДΓΓ БДLL and xFortyFourx gave me this solution, which turned out to be the best answer I was seeking, not sure why it was answered in a comment instead of an answer, though.

```
$("input:not([type='radio'], [type='text'])")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the **delegate()** method does not work well when the selector is not a string.  To get around this issue, just put your logic within your delegate handler

```
//Input types I do not want to select
var typeArray = ["text", "date"];

$("form").delegate("input", "click", function() {
    if($.inArray(this.type, typeArray) === -1) {
        //Put your logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I am trying to get all of the inputs except for a specific list of types, not A specific type.

Comment: Instead of making jQuery parse a complicated selector string, this allows you to pass a function selector, which is way more efficient.

Comment: This is good, but how can this work with the .delegate() function?

Comment: Yeah I couldn't get it to work either with the selector, so I just stuck the logic inside of the delegate event handler.

Comment: If I were only trying to get input with specific types I might use this, but as it stands the selector is cleaner. However, this gave me an idea that I used to filter my results after they were already bound.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out multiple types, you can do something like this:

```
$('input[type!="radio"][type!="text"]')
```